# I-adic completion of ring + profinite group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am a bit confused. Let $R$ be a ring and $I\subset R$ an ideal of $R$. The $I$-adic completion of $R$ is by definition $R^\wedge = \varprojlim R/I^n$. This ring is now complete with the inverse limit topology. But this ring need not be $I$-adically complete (if $I$ is not finitely generated for example). This is somehow confusing. The $I$-adic completion is not $I$-adically complete... My question is, what it means for a ring with the $I$-adic topology to be $I$-adically complete. The powers $I^n$ form a basis of neighbourhood of $0$ (in order to have the $I$-adic topology), they tend to zero (separatedness) and what does the surjectivity of the map $R\to \varprojlim R/I^n$ mean (in order to be $I$-adic complete)? Is there some easy way of thinking about it? And is there some easy way of thinking about the topology of $R^\wedge$ with the inverse limit topology? For instance, if $G$ is a profinite group, then it does not necessarily imply $G$ to be profinitely complete, right? But if $G$ is profinitely complete, i.e. $G=\varprojlim G/N$ with $N$ open normal subgroup of $G$, what does this actually mean topologically? Those $N$ form a nbhd-basis of $0$ and all their intersection is trivial and ...? And if $G=\varprojlim G_i$ for finite discrete groups $G_i$, does it mean that any finite quotient $G/U$ (for some open normal $U\subset G$) is of the form $G_j$ for some $j$?

Comment: Have you read the relevant Stacks project Tag? Namely,  https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05JA

Comment: also, in the profinite situation the issue does not exist, a profinite group is always the inverse limit of the quotients by open normal subgroups